# How to get all items by feature in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

How to get all task items by feature id?

I want to get all the items that belong to a particular feature. Is it possible to do it by using the Rest API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with the [Work Items - Get Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) API with the `$expand` parameter:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?$expand=relations&api-version=5.1
```

The `$expand=relations` parameter will return all the items that linked to the work item.